# Matrices with Three Nonzero Diagonals

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

How would you compute eigenvectors of matrices of the form

\begin{equation}
\nonumber
M =
\left( \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 a_1 & 0  & b_1&&&&&&&\\ 
0 &  a_2 & 0& b_2&&&&&&& \\
c_1 &0 &  a_3 & 0&b_3&&&&&& \\
&c_2&0&  a_4& 0&&&&&& \\
&&c_3&0& &&&&&& \\
&&&&&\ddots\\ \\
&&&&&& a_{n-3} & 0 & b_{n-3}& \\
&&&&& &0 & a_{n-2} & 0 & b_{n-2}\\
&&&&&&c_{n-3}& 0& a_{n-1}&  0\\
&&&&&&&c_{n-2}& 0 &a_n \\
\end{array} \right) 
\end{equation}

where all the omitted entries are null?

The particular matrix I'm dealing with has the additional property of being stochastic, so the principal eigenvalue is one.

Comment: If you're interested in the principal eigenvector, you're really just looking to compute $\ker(M - I)$.  Is the matrix row-stochastic or column-stochastic?

Answer (score 1):

I address the case in which $n$ is even.
If we conjugate with a permutation matrix corresponding to the permutation
$$
\pmatrix{1&2&3&\cdots& n/2 & n/2 +1 & n/2+2& \cdots & n \\
1&3&5&\cdots &n-1&2&4&\cdots&n}
$$
Then we end up with the similar matrix
$$
\pmatrix{
a_1&b_1\\
c_1&a_3&b_3\\
&c_3&\ddots\\
&&&&b_{n-3}\\
&&&c_{n-3}&a_{n-1}&\\
&&&&& a_2&b_2\\
&&&&&c_2&a_4&b_4\\
&&&&&&c_4 & \ddots
}
$$
which is to say that we have the [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition#Direct_sum) of two [tridiagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix) matrices.  In the odd case, we end up with a similar sum but the sizes of the blocks are not the same.

With that, we've reduced the problem to that of finding the eigenvalues of a tridiagonal matrix, which I'm guessing is slightly easier.

Note also that since this a reducible stochastic matrix (and in particular, the direct sum of two irreducible matrices) we'll end up with 2 linearly independent eigenvectors associated with $\lambda = 1$.